# Parse multiple numbers out of a string C#

Tags: string, parsing, numbers

How do I parse multiple numbers out of a string in C#? For instance, how do I get ALL the numbers out of this string: <3, 4, 4>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have numbers in a string separated by `,` So you can try this

```
        string st = "3, 4, 4";
        st = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(st, " ", "");
        //MessageBox.Show(st);
        string[] ans = st.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.Length; i++)
        {
            int num_At_i = Convert.ToInt32(ans[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(num_At_i + "");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a **regular expression** with capturing groups.

```
\<(\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\>/
```

Something like the following perhaps:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<(\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\>/");
Match match = regex.Match(myString);
if (match.Success){
   //Take matches from each capturing group here. match.Groups[n].Value;
}
else{
   //No match
}
```

Comment: Presumably there might be N number of `\d` between the brackets

Comment: @ConradFrix made that `\d+`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? Basic Regex:
`[0-9]+`